# Is there any difference between black supremacism and white supremacism

Tags: racism

Both movements appear to aim for separatism. I can see how they might disagree on immaterial historical claims. But in terms of practical actions they seem to me to be identical.

Is there any difference between black supremacism and white supremacism?

Comment: You'll need to pick representative movements for deeper analysis. Also "separatism" and "supremacism" are two different things even if they have a lot of overlap in terms of how they play out.

Comment: Many comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question.

Comment: I've never, ever heard of anything resembling black supremacism (i.e. claims that other races are inherently inferior to blacks and that they should rule the roost because of that).  Links or examples for what you are talking about, please.

Comment: What is your scope here? America? Global? South Africa?

Comment: There is a disagreement [in the chat discussion about an answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80153/discussion-on-answer-by-guest271314-is-there-any-difference-between-black-suprem) regarding what counts as a "supremacist" in the context of this question. Is a supremacist one who *seeks* to oppress people according to their philosophy and value system or one who *actively and successfully* oppresses people in practice? A clarification from the original author would be helpful.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: they [seem to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_supremacy) but most are incredibly obscure.

Comment: Per Philipp's comments, the question is pretty confusing; [Black separatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_separatism) and [Black supremacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_supremacy) are distinct notions, even if they may overlap in some concrete ideologies. In the white case, the overlap (between supremacy and separatism) is more severe in practice so that it's [hard to exemplify them separately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_supremacy#White_separatism).

Answer (score 4):

White supremacists have a history of exerting significant power in the west and using it to oppress people. Non-white supremacists have rarely had any significant power to enact their policies.

More over white supremacy was a mainstream political movement for a while, particularly in the 1930s and following decades, but black supremacy has never been so in the developed world.

Even ideologically they differ significantly. White supremacists tend to point to western civilization as proof that white people are superior, and use historical racist ideas about race in their arguments. Black supremacists tend to cite the poor treatment of black people by whites, particularly slavery, to create a moral argument in favour of subjugation and genocide.

In terms of practical actions white supremacists have a lot more "infrastructure" and their politics are at the fringes of powerful mainstream parties like the Republicans in the US and various far right parties in Europe. They have been able to enact policies that create systemic racism, both historically and in the present. Black supremacists have little political power outside of a few African nations.

Comment: This answer could be vastly improved by citing some sources. Especially considering that it is about such a controversial topic.

Comment: So would "a few African nations" be appropriate places to compare with "the west?"  Also, historically, is it the Republicans who had association with white supremacists?  Also, how much actual power do white supremacists have in "the west?" Something like 3000 KKK members left in the USA according to the ADL.  Compare that to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_of_Yahweh.

Comment: Took guts to even broach this question.  +1  Philipp is right though, you need to source your points if you can.

Comment: @puppetsock white supremacy was a well established part of the southern democrats until around the 50s when they started a mass exodus from the party. The Republicans went after this demographic in the 70s with the "southern strategy" and that's how we ended up where we are today. As for numbers, note the KKK is just one of many white supremacist groups/orgs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_white_nationalist_organizations#United_States

Comment: @puppetsock Our own current US president has both shown public support for and received support from neo-confederates and white supremacists.  He hasnt openly claimed the label for himself or restated their views, because dog whistling is effective.  And yes, historically the people who are currently Republicans are the ones who had associations with white supremacists.  When a block of voters and politicians switch parties, they dont get to blame their own deeds on the remainder of the previous coalition who fought against their positions and caused them to switch.  You just linked to a cult.

Comment: What is your scope for both WS and BS? It seems (although I may be misunderstanding) that you are comparing American WS with worldwide BS.

Comment: " Non-white supremacists have rarely had any significant power to enact their policies." Depends how you want to define that. Arguably tribal conflicts (e.g. Rwanda) can fall under this umbrella

Comment: "Even ideologically they differ significantly" I'd argue this is the only relevant part of the answer. The fact that white supremacists have had power in the past is more difference of circumstance than of the movements themselves

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: I don't think that distinction can be made. Circumstances influence ideology. That is a main reason why Black separatism is more common than Black supremacy in the US, in my opinion. Whereas in the white case it's hard to find any (US) examples of white separatism that aren't supremacist.

Comment: Which supremacism is worse in terms of pure ideology? Their ability to actually accomplish the task doesn't matter here